# Unpivoting a Pandas data frame, while keeping another column attached to the value column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of data, like:

```
| ----- | ------ | ------------ | ------ | ------------ |
| name  | height | height_units | weight | weight_units |
| ----- | ------ | ------------ | ------ | ------------ |
| Alice | 62     | in           | 116    | lb           |
| Bob   | 186    | cm           | 85     | kg           |
```

I want to unpivot it to:

```
| ----- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| name  | variable | value | units |
| ----- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| Alice | height   | 62    | in    |
| Bob   | height   | 186   | cm    |
| Alice | weight   | 116   | lb    |
| Bob   | weight   | 85    | kg    |
```

[`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) seems to be what I need... but I can't figure out how to keep the units column. Here's what I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob'],
    'height': [62, 186],
    'height_units': ['in', 'cm'],
    'weight': [116, 85],
    'weight_units': ['lb', 'kg'],
})

print("Original data frame:")
print(df)

print("\nUnpivoted, but without units:")
print(df.melt(id_vars=['name'], value_vars=['height', 'weight']))

print("\nUnpivoted, but with units:\n???")
```

Which outputs:

```
Original data frame:
    name  height height_units  weight weight_units
0  Alice      62           in     116           lb
1    Bob     186           cm      85           kg

Unpivoted, but without units:
    name variable  value
0  Alice   height     62
1    Bob   height    186
2  Alice   weight    116
3    Bob   weight     85

Unpivoted, but with units:
???
```

How can I keep that units column, attached to the appropriate variable?

Answer (score 3):

You could do a bit of massaging after pandas melt with `assign` and `rename` :

```
box = (df.melt(["name", "height", "weight"])
        .assign(height=lambda x: np.where(x.variable.str.startswith("height"), 
                                          x.height,
                                          x.weight),
                variable=lambda x: x.variable.str.split("_").str[0],
                )
        .drop("weight", axis=1)
        .rename(columns={"height": "value", "value": "units"})
         )


box


    name    value   variable    units
0   Alice   62          height  in
1   Bob     186         height  cm
2   Alice   116         weight  lb
3   Bob     85          weight  kg
```

Alternatively, you could reshape the columns, by appending `_value` to `height` and `weight` :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("(height|weight)$", lambda x: f"{x}_value")
```

Now reorder the columns, so that `value` and `units` are at the start of the words.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_").str[::-1].str.join("_")

df.columns

Index(['name', 'height_value', 'height_units', 'weight_value', 'weight_units'], dtype='object')
```

It should be easy to unpivot, using `pd.wide_to_long` :

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                ["value", "units"], 
                i="name", 
                sep="_", 
                j="variable", 
                suffix=".+")

                     value  units
name    variable        
Alice   height        62    in
Bob     height       186    cm
Alice   weight       116    lb
Bob     weight        85    kg
```

**UPDATE**:
You could also use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

(df.rename(columns = lambda x: f"{x}_value" 
                              if "_" not in x 
                              and x != "name" 
                              else x)
 .pivot_longer(index = "name", 
               names_to = ("variable", ".value"), 
               names_sep = "_")
)


    name    variable    value   units
0   Alice   height      62      in
1   Bob     height      186     cm
2   Alice   weight      116     lb
3   Bob     weight      85      kg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use df.melt twice respectively : 1. to the value of the height and weight 2. to the unit of the height and weight. And then concat them.

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['name',], value_vars=['height', 'weight'])
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['name'], value_name='unit', value_vars=['height_units', 'weight_units'])
print(df1)
print(df2)
print("\nUnpivoted, but with units:")
print( pd.concat([df1, df2['unit']], axis=1) )
```

You can get df1 and df2 as followed:

```
    name variable  value
0  Alice   height     62
1    Bob   height    186
2  Alice   weight    116
3    Bob   weight     85
    name      variable unit
0  Alice  height_units   in
1    Bob  height_units   cm
2  Alice  weight_units   lb
3    Bob  weight_units   kg
```

Finally, the result table:

```
name variable  value unit
0  Alice   height     62   in
1    Bob   height    186   cm
2  Alice   weight    116   lb
3    Bob   weight     85   kg
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but I feel like there must be some more elegant solution... like what if I wanted 10 columns instead of 2, I'd have to make 10 separate passes over it and then concatenate them? Shouldn't this just be like a one liner in some built in function, I imagine it's a common use case? But maybe not, since I couldn't find an answer when Googling...

Comment: If there are more columns needed to pass, I might define the list of the value_vars and use for loop to run the full process...